# Re: A JavaScript Fn that accepts unknown # args - call Fn wrks - call via var does not

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, this, apply

Learning how to write JS Fn that accepts an unknown number of arguments.

```
function foo(a,b,c,d){
    //do something
    //return something
}

var bar = function () {
    var arg = Array.from(arguments);
    var lastIndx = arg.length;
    var parArray = arg.slice(1,lastIndx);
    var argMnts = arguments[0];
    return arguments[0].apply(this, parArray);
};
```

calling bar thus works:

```
bar(foo,1,4,3,7);
```

calling it like so:

```
var tester = bar(foo,1,4,3,7);
tester();
```

results in: tester is not a function

From my research I suspected it might have to do with the scope of "this" or arguments so I assigned their values to variables, subbed the vars, and the result was the same.

Some insight would be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, calling `bar()` returns whatever the results of calling `foo(...)` is.  So, if you want to be able to do this:

```
var tester = bar(foo,1,4,3,7);
tester();
```

Then, `foo(...)` has to return another function that can get assigned to `tester` and can then get called again.

---

If, instead of the way it is above, if you don't want `bar(foo, ...)` to actually call `foo()`, but want it to return a function that will then call `foo()` with the appropriate arguments, you can change `bar()` to this:

```
var bar = function () {
    var args = Array.from(arguments);
    var fn = args.shift();
    var self = this;
    return function() {
        return fn.apply(self, args);
    }
};

var tester = bar(foo,1,4,3,7);
tester();
```

Here, `bar()` returns a function, that (when called) will call `foo()`.

---

Or, with the right ES6 support, you could use rest parameters;

```
var bar = function (fn, ...args) {
    var self = this;
    return function() {
        return fn.apply(self, args);
    }
};
```

or, you could use `.bind()` with rest parameters and the spread operator:

```
var bar = function (fn, ...args) {
    return fn.bind(this, ...args);
};
```

Comment: `Array.from` is from ES6, so I think it's safe to assume they are using it.

Comment: @4castle - ES6 support does not always come in a giant monolith where you have it all or don't have any of it.  For example, node 4.x has `Array.from()`, but not rest or spread.  node 5.x has `Array.from()` and spread, but not rest.  node 6.x has all three.  Anyway, my answer now offers several choices.

Comment: I learned alot from this thank you!  regarding your answer:  return fn.apply(self, args);  wouldn't fn need to refer to the first index of the args [] and args be replaced with an [] containing all indices but the first?

Comment: @InaMastabba - That's what `args.shift()` does.  `args.shift()` grabs the first item from the `args` array and the others are moved down in the array.  So, you then have `fn` as the first argument and `args` as the rest of the arguments.